# welcome/cat/0 can't access method cat() in controller welcome.php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a controller `welcome.php` and a method `cat()`. This is the query string `http://localhost/CodeIgniterhi/?welcome/cat/0`. When I click on that link I can't access the method `cat()` in controller `welcome.php`. Why? Is there any routing problem? My default router is welcome/index.

Comment: it could be because you're missing the index.php out of the URL, try this address: http://localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/welcome/cat/0

Comment: unless you have removed it with htaccess files and changing the config file, if so, ignore the above

Comment: please post your controller too. Did you removed **index.php** from url?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you removed `index.php` from your urls, the problem is that you have query char in url

```
/CodeIgniterhi/?welcome/cat/0
```

should be

```
/CodeIgniterhi/welcome/cat/0
```

if you have problem that you can't remove the query char `?` you should try enabling in `config/config.php` this:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';
```

sincerily is not the best practice to use query strings in url, they will look not SEO friendly